# How to add the contents of a directory, but not the directory itself using git

Tags: git, github

I'm making a website and layout of the files looks like this:

```
-Project
---build
---source
```

I'd like to push just the contents of the build folder to gh-pages branch on github, but not the directory itself (so that myname.github.io/project will lead to the project and not myname.github.io/project/build).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: One way to accomplish this would be to create symbolic links from files in 'build' folder into the current one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure: just commit the tree directly.  It's already in your repo, just add the commit for it and point the ref at it:

```
git update-ref refs/heads/gh-pages $(
        git commit-tree -p gh-pages -m "built pages" master:build
)
```

For first-time use just omit the `-p gh-pages` part, or to automate it the sugar's

```
pages=`git rev-parse gh-pages`
git update-ref refs/heads/gh-pages $(
        git commit-tree ${pages:+-p gh-pages} -m "built pages" master:build
)
```

Comment: Fantastic, that's done the job, thanks a lot! I don't understand a lot of it, but hopefully a few searches can clear that up.